# :terminal, change prompt color or background color

Tags: terminal, color

When I run `:terminal`, I have a combination of blue color of the prompt over a grey background and I can barely read what is written, see attached image.
What options can I add to `:ter` in such a way I have either black background or a specific prompt color?
I tried `:ter background dark`, `:ter background=dark`, etc but with no success.

[image]

Comment: If you drill into the two tags you applied to your post, you will find hundreds of similar, or likely, exact questions. Have you tried any of the accepted answers there?

Comment: Ok, then can you please send me some link? The only answers that I found are all based on `:set`. As stated, I need a solution for `:ter`. The end goal is to call `vim -c terminal <options for dark background only in the terminal>` directly from the bash, leaving the `desert` `colorscheme` for the editor on top. See image above.

Answer (score 2):

> ... in such a way I have either black background ...

```
:hi terminal ctermbg=16 guibg=#000000
```

> or a specific prompt color?

`:h g:terminal_ansi_colors` as in https://github.com/vim/colorschemes/blob/02a0a716fff23125bfcbb8596d5d1b87d590e662/colors/desert.vim#L19

```
let g:terminal_ansi_colors = ['#7f7f8c', '#cd5c5c', '#9acd32', '#bdb76b', '#75a0ff', '#eeee00', '#cd853f', '#666666', '#8a7f7f', '#ff0000', '#89fb98', '#f0e68c', '#6dceeb', '#ffde9b', '#ffa0a0', '#c2bfa5']
```

Comment: Nice! But what if I want to pass it as an option when I call vim from the bash, i.e. `vim -c "terminal <options for dark background only in the terminal OR use a certain prompt color scheme>` ?

Comment: add it to your vimrc with conditional check of global variable, set this variable in `-c` option in command-line.